# tfpt.exe online /diff sees all of my writeable files as changes. What's going on?

Tags: tfs, tfs-power-tools, tf-cli

I made my entire local workspace read-write then edited a couple of files.

When I run tfpt.exe online with the /diff option (with /preview) tfpt reports that all my local workspace files will be pended as edits.

The files are all XML but witout an XML file name extension.

Any ideas please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pantelif solution is the simplest one. tfpt online, even with diff flag treats any RW file as modified.

Comment: So what's the point of the /diff switch? It's completely redundant?!

Comment: diff is useful if file was modified but kept the read-only attribute.

Answer (score 3):

After having executed `tfpt online`, try a `tfpt uu` to undo all files that are unchanged.
 This should result with only the files you have edited in pending changes list.